# Fetching only required string from the list

Tags: python, string, list

Suppose i had list as below

```
list_fields = ['Full-Time',
 'Options:',
 'Express your interest',
 'Email this to a friend',
 'More information about this job:',
 'Overview:',
 'A',
 'Parasite',
 'position is cool',
 'Are you a LEADER?',
 'For sure there',
 'Hello doing?',
 'If so you will EXCEL.',
 'Bring your skills',
 'programs and procedures']
```

what i am trying to do is collecting all the strings after `overview`, i mean need to ignore the strings before `overview` string. There may many strings before and after `overview`, but want to collect all the strings only after `overview` as a list and want to make them as a single string by using something like `''.join([list_fields])`
Sorry if i am using words again and again, can anyone please tell me how to do this

```
Edited Code:
```

1. Can we only fetch from after "overview:" to before 'Bring your skills'.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that the string is litterally `"Overview:"`, you can do

```
''.join(list_fields[list_fields.index("Overview:") + 1:])
```

This uses `list.index()` to determine the index of `"Overview:"` in the list, and uses slicing to get the sublist starting at the index after `"Overview:"`.

Comment: I think @Sven Marnach's solution is right. But I'd rather "join" the list into string first and then do the search. One advantage is that -- if the string you are looking for is not in it, it ends up with a empty string. One disadvantage is that, it will NOT distinguish whether the string is a key or it is part of a key. So I guess the solution depends on your problem context.

Comment: @dolaameng It could even be two keys joined together by some small chance.

Comment: Actually the string overview: is fiexed , it will be there for sure

Comment: @jamylak: yes it could happen. But considering the elements in the list are actually WORDS, I think it could even be a good thing -- e.g., for text processing tasks, the word "overview" could be accidently delimited by a newline or space. And if it's a text scrapper text, I dont think it is a good idea to use a "word" as a probe. : )

Comment: but here the overview: string is hard cored, it will be there for sure

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Can we restrict the list only up to 'If so you will EXCEL.', i mean can we collect the strings after "overview:" and before 'Bring your skills',here both are fixed strings.

Comment: @shivakrishna: Yes of course – Search that string with `list.index()` and use it as the end index fo the slice.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools as it

list(it.dropwhile(lambda x: not x.lower().startswith('overview'), list_fields))[1:]
```

Comment: This is the best solution of you don't know exactly what the text is.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a[a.index(4):]

>> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

So in your case you can do:

```
"".join(list_fields[list_fields.index("Overview:"):])
```

To answer the questions in the comments:

```
def my_slice(l,a,b):
    try:
        a_idx = l.index(a)
        b_idx = l.index(b)

    except ValueError:
        return []

    if a_idx > b_idx:
        a_idx, b_idx = b_idx, a_idx
    return l[a_idx:b_idx+1]

my_slice(list_fields,'Overview:','Bring your skills')
```

Comment: what if we want to collect only from 2 to 6 that is [2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: No actually i had to find through words itself because if some of the words increased in the list ultimately the index will be changed right, need to fetch exactly from after "Overview:" to 'Bring your skills'

Comment: if you know which is index comes first (2 comes before 6) then: `a[a.index(2):a.index(6)+1]`

Comment: you can try this: `b = a[a.index(2):a.index(6)+1]` `if not b: b = a[a.index(6):a.index(2)+1]`

Answer (score -1):

Slice should work with index. This doesn't handle the error if not found.

```
lstResults = list_fields[list_fields.index('overview'):]
```

Comment: You're collecting the Items before 'overview' instead of after.